# Filtrado de líneas con grep UNIX

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal, grep

Tengo varias dudas puntuales, ambas relacionadas con comandos del terminal de Ubuntu y que no he conseguido sacar solución.

- Mostrar las líneas del fichero que contienen el número exacto “2”, es decir, que contengan esa cadena literalmente y no dentro de otra. Por ejemplo, no debe mostrar líneas que contengan la cantidad 12 o 250.

En esta si utilizo `grep 2 fichero` me lista también las líneas que son 222, 250 12 y demás, que no debería salir por pantalla.

- Crear un nuevo fichero que contenga las líneas que no tengan caracteres numéricos (0, 1, 2, …, 9). En esta no se los comandos que utilizar, seguramente sea por tuberías y me he metido en las ayudas de los comandos `grep --help` y muchos otros y ninguno se corresponde a lo que pide, quitar lineas con caracteres numéricos.

  ```
  Este es un fichero de ejemplo para realizar el ejecicio 1
  esta linea va a estar repetida
  linea con caracter numerico: 20
  linea sin caracter numerico
  esta linea va a estar repetida
  z: esta linea ordenada en orden inverso tiene que ser la primera
  esta linea va a estar repetida
  ```
- Proponer una instrucción con tan solo dos comandos en la tubería, o sea, “comando 1 | comando 2” a la siguiente instrucción `cat [ruta]fichero | grep cadena_caracteres | wc -l`. En esta no sé los comandos que utilizar con solo 2 comandos. He encontrado uno de tres: `cat < [ruta]fichero | grep cadena_caracteres | wc –l` pero tiene que ser de dos.

Comment: Fernando: en lugar de tres cuestiones en una pregunta, sería mejor que hicieras tres preguntas diferentes. Son gratis y ayudan a tener la información ordenada :)

Comment: Nótese por cierto que `cat [ruta]fichero | grep cadena_caracteres` se puede simplificar con un mero `grep cadena_caracteres ruta/fichero`.

Comment: @Fernando No deberían realizarse ediciones triviales de preguntas. Por favor, evita realizar ediciones minúsculas que realmente no mejoran las preguntas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te comprendo, el problema es que para realizar esos ejercicios tienes que conocer un poco de [expresiones regulares](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular).

> Mostrar las líneas del fichero que contienen el número exacto "2", es
>   decir, que contengan esa cadena literalmente y no dentro de otra

Teniendo como ejemplo:

```
$ cat test.txt
1212
999992
2
21
22
222
2
1212
```

Puedes usar una mezcla de `^` (expresión regular para el inicio de la línea) y `$` (expresión regular para el final de la línea):

```
$ grep "^2$" test.txt
2
2
```

Si, además, quieres saber en qué línea del archivo se encuentran las coincidencias puedes usar el flag `-n`:

```
$ grep -n "^2$" test.txt 
3:2
7:2
```

> Crear un nuevo fichero que contenga las líneas que no tengan
>   caracteres numéricos (0, 1, 2, …, 9)

Teniendo como ejemplo:

```
$ cat test.txt
Este es un fichero de ejemplo para realizar el ejecicio 1
esta linea va a estar repetida
linea con caracter numerico: 20
linea sin caracter numerico
esta linea va a estar repetida
z: esta linea ordenada en orden inverso tiene que ser la primera
esta linea va a estar repetida
```

Vamos por partes.

Existe una expresión regular para poder encontrar todos los dígitos y es usando `[0-9]` (los numerós del 0 al 9):

```
$ grep "[0-9]" test.txt
Este es un fichero de ejemplo para realizar el ejecicio 1
linea con caracter numerico: 20
```

Pero esto no es lo que quieres, lo que tú quieres es la inversa. Para esto puedes usar el flag `-v` para invertir la búsqueda (es decir, todas las líneas que NO tienen caracteres numéricos):

```
$ grep "[0-9]" -v test.txt 
esta linea va a estar repetida
linea sin caracter numerico
esta linea va a estar repetida
z: esta linea ordenada en orden inverso tiene que ser la primera
esta linea va a estar repetida
```

Para guardarlo en un archivo nuevo simplemente redirecciona la salida:

```
$ grep "[0-9]" -v test.txt > test2.txt
$ cat test2.txt 
esta linea va a estar repetida
linea sin caracter numerico
esta linea va a estar repetida
z: esta linea ordenada en orden inverso tiene que ser la primera
esta linea va a estar repetida
```

> Proponer una instrucción con tan solo dos comandos en la tubería, o
>   sea, “comando 1 | comando 2” a la siguiente instrucción cat
>   [ruta]fichero | grep cadena_caracteres | wc -l

No se si he entendido mal, pero esta es la más sencilla, simplemente usa el grep al archivo directamente:

```
$ grep cadena_caracteres [ruta]fichero | wc -l
```