# Encontrar los directorios y ficheros del directorio actual que contengan una determinada cadena

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal, búsquedas

Mostrar por pantalla todos los directorio,  sólo directorios, del directorio actual que contengan en su nombre  la cadena “pra”.

Tengo esto:

```
find . -type d
```

Mostrar por pantalla todos los ficheros,  sólo ficheros, del directorio actual que contengan en su nombre  la cadena “pra”.

Tengo esto:

```
find . -type f
```

Pero está mal porque me sale un bucle infinito. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme con ellos?

Comment: Fernando: como te comentamos en otra de tus preguntas, formula una sola pregunta cada vez. Aquí hay dos, como en la [anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/104855/83) y [otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/104344/83) más.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Directorios:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name \*pra\*
```

Ficheros:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*pra\*
```

`-maxdepth` indica cuantos niveles de directorios se *bajará*. `1` equivale a *no entres en subdirectorios*.

`-maxdepth X` es una *opción*; debe ir **antes** de las expresiones.

Para que la *shell* no te *expanda* los posibles comodines que uses, tienes 2 opciones:

1. Colocar `\` **antes** de los caracteres *comodín* ( `-name \*pra\*` )
2. Usar comillas *simples* `'` ( `-name '*pra*'` )

<sub>Gracias a @fedorqui por recordarme que las comillas existen :-)</sub>

Comment: también puedes usar comillas simples `-name '*pra*'` y así no tienes que escapar nada.

Comment: @fedorqui Cierto. La costumbre de apenas usarlas. Lo añado a la respuesta :-)

Answer (score 3):

Las soluciones con `find` son prácticas y correctas.

Por completitud, podemos realizar esta tarea también con la expansión parámetros:

```
for archivo in *pra*
do
   [ -f "$archivo" ] && echo "$archivo"
done
```

Por partes:

- `for archivo in *pra*`: expande en una lista de elementos cuyo nombre contenga "pra". Como estos elementos pueden ser ficheros, directorios, links... es necesario añadir la siguiente validación:
- `[ -f "$archivo" ] && echo "$archivo"` que mira si se trata de un fichero, en cuyo caso escribe su valor por pantalla.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con:

```
find . -type f -name 'pra*'
```

La opción `-name` permite especificar el nombre del archivo o directorio que se busca. La sintaxis más sencilla es como la de la *shell* y en este caso, hay que poner el término a buscar entre comillas para que la *shell* no expanda lo que queremos buscar y lo interprete literalmente. Unas comillas dobles también servirían.

Comment: Hola Álvaro. Tomo nota de la sugerencia. Creo que el código habla por sí mismo, pero he añadido una explicación. Supongo que de este modo queda más claro.